# Open a (recovered) Microsoft Word document from 14 years ago

Tags: microsoft-word, file-recovery, version

I have a Microsoft Word document that I wrote 14 years ago (in 2006), it is text-only.
I do not remember which version of Microsoft Word I was using to write it, but the OS was Windows XP (in a different language that my current PC), and the file extension is ".doc".
I changed computers several times since then, but always kept that file in some HDDs.

Now I want to read this document again.
I plugged my external HDD to my current computer (Windows 10) ; and Explorer tells me that the file type is "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document".
On my PC I have the "Word App" installed (not sure which version that means ; it is installed in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE").

When I try to open my .doc file with this version of Word, I get this message box:

[image]

I tried several encodings but the text preview was always garbled.
I remember that 10 years ago (in 2010) my laptop crashed, I brought it to a shop that salvaged its disk, I think this file was one of the retrieved data.

Is there any way I can read the contents of my document again?

Comment: Very unlikely...

Comment: Did you try with some older version like MS word 2007?

Comment: Did you try with some older version like MS word 2007?

Comment: I think Windows is just assuming Microsoft format based on the .doc extension. AFAICR Word would normally recognise a Word format document regardless of the extension, which would suggest that it isn’t a Word doc. Could it be a doc created by something else such as WordPerfect (which also used .doc)? Judging by the null, out and pop I wondered if it might be some kind of binary Postscript, perhaps change the extension to .eps and see if you can insert it into Word.

Answer (score 1):

I would search for an old word viewer program that dates from 2010 or so.  Microsoft distributed these free so they shouldn't be too hard to find.